# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field PUBLIC_ONLY

Tags: android, crash, proguard

I don't have any problem in my app when it's in debug mode.
But when I compile my app, it crashes in an activity that is related to pay for upgrading application.

I guessed that is because of ProGuard. so I added this line to my proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keep class ir.ali_kh_y.telegramschool.GoldenVersionActivity { *; }
```

And I also tried this one:

```
-keep class ir.ali_kh_y.telegramschool.GoldenVersionActivity.class { *; }
```

But when I opened that activity, my app crashed again...

**Error**:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: ir.ali_kh_y.telegramschool, PID: 6838

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field PUBLIC_ONLY of type Lcom/b/a/a/a/a/a/a/e$a; in class Lcom/b/a/a/a/a/a/a/e$a; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.b.a.a.a.a.a.a.e$a' appears in /data/app/ir.ali_kh_y.telegramschool-1/base.apk)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotation(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:2352)
at com.b.a.a.a.a.a.c.e.u$a.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at com.b.a.a.a.a.a.c.e.u$a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.b.a.a.a.a.a.c.t.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at com.b.a.b.b(Unknown Source)
at com.b.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
at b.a.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
at b.a.a.e.<init>(Unknown Source)
at b.a.a.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
at b.a.a.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ir.ali_kh_y.telegramschool.GoldenVersionActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**proguard-rules.pro**:

```
-ignorewarnings
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
-keep public class ir.adad.client.** { *; }
-keep class ir.ali_kh_y.telegramschool.GoldenVersionActivity.class { *; }
```

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.ali_kh_y.telegramschool"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            useProguard true
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    compile 'io.nivad.billing:library:0.1.8'
    compile 'com.auth0:java-jwt:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.simbiose:Encryption:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'ir.adad.androidsdkv3:AdadSDKv3:3.3.1'
    compile 'me.cheshmak:analytics:2.0.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
}
```

Now there is two questions:

1. What should I do to solve this problem?
2. If I use `-keep class ...` is it safe for my app?
3. If it's not safe, Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
That was because of Nivad. I had to add this to my proguard rules:

```
-keep class io.nivad.** { *; }
-keep class com.auth0.jwt.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.**
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn com.auth0.jwt.**
```